# PeakEq center frequency does not match frequency response

Tags: biquad, parametric-eq

Following the [Cookbook](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt) i calculed these coefficients:

```
b0: 1,001511976106398860153
b1: -1,999957163328258458179
b2: 0,998488023893601139847
a0: 1,000379791226643000357
a1: -1,999957163328258458179
a2: 0,999620208773356999643
```

For `Fs = 48000`, `Fc = 50`, `Q = 4.318477`, `dbGain = 12`.

Applying a pink noise and analyzing the frequency response showed me that the real center frequency is approx. `93 Hz`

What i want is know why this happened and how to get right center frequency.

This is actually frequency response.
[image: Frequency Response]

The code used to implement is the following:

```
double filter(double in)
{

    double y = .0;

    y = (b0 / a0) * in + (b1 / a0) * xb[0] + (b2 / a0) * xb[1]
        - (a1 / a0) * yb[0] - (a2 / a0) * yb[1];

    yb[1] = yb[0];
    yb[0] = y;
    xb[1] = xb[0];
    xb[0] = in;

    return y;
}
```

`xb` and `yb` are two double arrays.

Comment: Your coefficients looks to be OK (gives right response in Octave) so, maybe it's an issue in your analyzing ...

Comment: @JuhaP edited the question, but it is not a analyzing issue, i was able to hear the issue.

Comment: could be an implementation issue.  can you show the code that implements $$ y[n] = b_0 x[n]+b_1 x[n-1]+b_2 x[n-2]-a_1 y[n-1]-a_2 y[n-2] $$??  are you dividing the other five coefficients by $a_0$?

Comment: @Victor Paste the coefficients to applet here:  http://www.earlevel.com/main/2016/12/08/filter-frequency-response-grapher/ and set the fs and plot parameters to see it's not the coefficients behind the issue you're having there.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson added to the question.

Comment: @JuhaP indeed. is not the coeffs.

Comment: how flat is the noise that is $x[n]$?  it says it's pink.  does your spectrum plot compensate for that? unless your compiler is smarter than the average bear, your code is quite inefficient because of the five division operations.  you should predivide `a0` into the other 5 coefficients and just use those values. you got the correct signs (subtracting) the `a1` and `a2` terms. other than that, if the noise is known to be white and this is an FFT magnitude spectrum of the output, then the issue must be that of scaling on the log frequency axis of the plot, notwithstanding  your listening test.

Comment: Could it just be a wrong fs used somewhere in analyzing (your coeffs are fixed for 48kHz...)?

Comment: JuhaP Yes, the Fs used to calculate the coeffs are always 48kHz.

@robertbristow-johnson it is a pink noise, "does your spectrum plot compensate for that?" i dont known. I will fix the divisions. about the listening test im very sure that the gain is not aplied to 50Hz... and about the spectrum i think its ok because the lowpass and highpass filters coincide with the spectrum.

Comment: What I ment with wrong fs was like (with samplerate fixed coefficients) if you double the samplerate you get the fc point doubled as well ... I don't know if this fenomen could happen when testing with pink noise as well in situation when noise samplerate is not matching with filter "requirement" and/or "analyzer samplerate" ... meaning if samplerate of your pink noise is 24kHz ... or 96kHz ... does it give different result?

Comment: let me give some details, the audio data is comming from a [Jack](jackaudio.org) server, which is setup to 48kHz sample rate and a `1024` buffer size in that manner that all audio data that goes trought my application is sampled at 48kHz.

Comment: Does one of my coefficients give proper plot result? `1.0000 -2.0004 1.0004 0.99943 -2.00037 1.00095`  or `1.0000 -2.0013 1.0015 0.99773 -2.00135 1.00379` Let the samplerate settings be as you wrote above (i.e. 48kHz).

Comment: Found the issue, it was: the app has two input channel (L, R) and i was send both to same filter state (so same feedback buffer), creating another filter state and sending each channel to each filter state solved the problem.